# Salesforce Text Parsing Trigger

Tags: apex, json

i have a JSON field separate by semicolon, for example

[Quantity:"5", unit:"3",unitprice:"50.00"}

These are submitted via an external process and write into this field.

if(JsonField =! null()
    {
//Run logic
}

Requirements:

I want to take those values and insert them via a trigger into detail records. Can anyone tell me at a high level of how to go about this, or link me to details about this?

```
Detail__c record = trigger.new[0]; // THIS is where I'm getting my error right now 

Map<String, Detail__c> data = (Map<String, Detail__c>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(record.get('Detail.MDetails__c')); 

// Iterate over each key in the map (field name) 
for(String field : data.keySet()) { // Put the map data into your SObject record
    // NOTE: If your JSON data is not correctly typed you will need to 
    // use field describe information to convert it to the correct 
    // type for the field it is being placed in. 
    record.put(field, data.get(field)); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say you are trying to put the values into detail records, I am assuming you mean that you want to put the values into fields on THIS detail record. To do this, you can simply use dynamic apex.

Let's assume you have the following JSON from your example above (I have made some corrections to it so that it is valid JSON) in a field named "JSON_Data__c":

```
{  
  "Quantity":5,
  "Unit__c":3,
  "UnitPrice":50.00,
  "Description": "What a great record!"
}
```

You can deserialize this into a map and use dynamic apex to place it into your current record in the trigger:

```
// DO NOT ACTUALLY DO THIS VARIABLE ASSIGNMENT
//  Use a bulkified trigger pattern do to this in
//  a loop for all records in the trigger.
SObject record = trigger.new[0];

// Use the untyped deserialize method to turn your data into a generic map
Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(record.get('JSON_Data__c'));

// Iterate over each key in the map (field name)
for(String field : data.keySet()) {

  // Put the map data into your SObject record
  // NOTE: If your JSON data is not correctly typed you will need to
  //  use field describe information to convert it to the correct
  //  type for the field it is being placed in.
  record.put(field, data.get(field));
}
```

This becomes a little more complicated if you need to use the field describe information to ensure you have the correct data type, or if your JSON does not contain actual field names (so you need to convert strings to field names) but the basic principles still apply.

Comment: So I'm trying to do this right now, and I keep getting the- Method does not exist or incorrect signature error. I've got my field in where the 'JSON_Data' is, and my appropriate objects filled out in the Map piece as well. 

Not sure what exactly the JSON.DeserializedUntyped does as this is my first time using it, but it keeps telling me that the method doesn't exist.

Comment: I am not sure if the typo is just in your comment or also in your code, but in your comment you misspelled the method name. Here is a link to the Salesforce doc on the method: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped

Comment: Yeah its definitely just a typo, my apologies. So I'm looking at the link and there are some good examples in here, I just have a couple questions. So the values of these fields will always be unknown until they are submitted, and the fields in the example seem to be hardcoded. You mentioned that Dynamic apex would solve this issue. I've followed your example above and this is what I have.

Comment: Detail__c record = trigger.new[0];

// THIS is where I'm getting my error right now
Map<String, Detail__c> data = (Map<String, Detail__c>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(record.get('Detail.MDetails__c'));

// Iterate over each key in the map (field name)
for(String field : data.keySet()) {

  // Put the map data into your SObject record
  // NOTE: If your JSON data is not correctly typed you will need to
  //  use field describe information to convert it to the correct
  //  type for the field it is being placed in.
  record.put(field, data.get(field));
    
    
 }

Comment: You must cast the result into a Map<String, Object> if that is what your data is. If you are casting to a Map<String, Detail__c> you are saying that your data is a map where each key is a string and each value is a Detail__c value (this is a string?). If you then had data with an Integer in it, your cast would fail because an Integer cannot be a value of Detail__c. By making the value a generic object you are saying "We have some data, but we don't need to care about what type it is yet". The type comes into play when you do your dynamic apex: record.put(String fieldName, Object value).

Comment: A type mismatch between the fieldName specified and the Object type will cause an error at run-time. This means that you need to be sure that your JSON is correctly typed. Sending something like { "quantity" : 5 } would be fine, but {"quantity" : "5" } would cause a problem because your quantity field is a number and you just tried to give it a string with record.put("quantity", "5").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31825/discussion-between-d-s-and-christian).